# if I am making a file path, should which of these is faster?

Tags: c, file

So I am making code to make a file path from a name.

```
sprintf(FilePath, "%s/%s", DirPath, FileName);
```

and

```
strcpy(FilePath, DirPath);
strcat(FilePath, "/");
strcat(FilePath, FileName);
```

Which of these is faster/which should I use? In both cases I have malloc ed enough memory.

Comment: This very probably isn't going to be give a measurable effect. Be careful that this is not secure, and that if the `FilePath` string garanteed to be longer than `DirPath + Filepath + 2`, the program is going to be insecure. Use `snprintf` instead.

Comment: In my tests the `strcpy` etc method was about 10 times faster, with a fairly short `DirPath`. The break-even point was when `DirPath` has about 450 characters.

Comment: @toasted_flakes I am doing `malloc(strlen(DirPath) + strlen(FilePath) + 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- dont call `strlen()` more than once for any string
- instead: *remember* the length and reuse it
- compute the position *where you are* in the string
- remember that `strcat()` needs to rescan the destination string every time just to find its *current* end [leading to quadratic behaviour](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/)

---

```
static char *construct_path(char*pathname,char*filename)
{
char *result;
size_t plen, flen;

plen = strlen(pathname);
flen = strlen(filename);

result= malloc(plen+flen+2);
if(!result)return NULL;

memcpy(result, pathname, plen);
result[plen]='/';
memcpy(result+plen+1, filename, flen);
result[plen+1+flen] = 0;

return result;
}
```

---

Normally, the *caller* could already know the `strlen()`, for example for constant paths.

Comment: From my above comment, for the longer path name (450) this takes half the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf(FilePath, "%s/%s", DirPath, FileName);
```

is faster, because the second version has to compute the end of string twice in the `strcat` function calls.

`sprintf` composes the string while retaining the last string character all the time, no need to recompute it.

Comment: The problem is (*at least*), that the printf-family copies twice. (and, for sanity, you should use `snprintf()`, which is even more expensive)

Answer (score 0):

With POSIX, you can write

```
p = FilePath;
p = stpcpy(p, DirPath);
*p++ = '/';
p = stpcpy(p, Filename);
```